# Unknown tag (form:form) JSP page warning in Spring MVC Login Application

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am getting unknown form tag warning, Unknown tag (form:form) in spring mvc login validation application. How to resolve this. Please suggest me to fix this.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Cable Vision UserLogin </title>
</head>
<body>
  <form:form id="login" action="login.do" method="post"
       commandName="loginDetails">
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="3"><h3>Cable Vision UserLogin</h3></td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><label>UserName</label></td>
          <td><form:input path="userName"></form:input></td>
          <td><font color="red"><form:errors path="userName"></form:errors></font></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label>Password</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="Password"></form:input></td></td>
            <td><font color="blue"><form:errors path="Password"></form:errors></font></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center"><font color="red"><form:errors/></font></td> 
          </tr>  
       </table>
       </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you put the jar for the taglib?

Comment: I have added spring dependencies in pom.xml apart from that I have added for jdbc. thats it. I havent added any jars specific to spring.

Comment: When using a taglib like this you normally place the .jar for the taglib under appcontext/web-inf/lib/, and usually also a .tld file under appcontext/web-inf/

Comment: ok. I am new for spring mvc so am not aware of it. So I need to place the jar files in web-inf/lib right? In web.xml, do I need to do any changes apart from including it?

Comment: *"Please suggest me to fix this."* :-)

Comment: No the jars need to be present in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory, that is all.

Comment: I have included jstl1.2 jar in web-inf/lib

Comment: ok Bart. Thanks I did

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine for all attributes which have been defined in form:form tag. Whatever you can check two thinks

(1) Rebuild your application 
(2) Check your code for action="login.do" that, how have you configured this in xml.